How to override __len__ return type in python?
I am trying to implement a class Foo that when we call len(foo) will return an instance of another class MyCoolIntType instead of an int. Something like the following:
class Foo(object):
  def __len__(self) -> MyCoolIntType:
    return MyCoolIntType(self.size)

Of course, I keep geeting TypeError: 'MyCoolIntType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
What I imagine is happening is that when I call len from stdlib, the internal implementation does a type check to ensure that the result from obj.__len__() is an integer, and is raising in an exception.
So I guess my question can also be interpreted as "How do I re-declare a function (len()) from the stdlib in python?"
PS: I know I can work around it by just declaring a property size in my class, but I'm curious if it would be possible to use len to return MyCoolIntType

This isn't just about type declarations. The implementation of len() is apparently doing return int(obj.__len__()). That call to int() requires that your return value be convertible to an integer.

What is your use case? Everyone who calls len() expects it to return an integer. E.g. when they do for i in range(len(x)):

So even if you can "fix" len() so it doesn't get an error, you'll probably cause an error somewhere else. These dependencies go all the way up the chain.

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding here, python type annotations are merely hints for people reading code (or static analysis tools). It has nothing to do with the errors you are seeing or how to fix them. __len__ and other magic methods act as hooks, and you must conform to what the documentation says about how the methods should be implemented. Just like if you were using a third party API that provided a callback parameter, the documentation will say something like "the callback will be provided a single positional argument and must return a string" or whatever

IOW, python doesn't have function declarations, or any declarations really (maybe with the exception of global or nonlocal), and methods don't really have a return type other than what the method actually returns at runtime

Why is MyCoolIntType not convertible to int in the first place? If the implementation of len accepts anything that is convertible to int, then as long as MyCoolIntType defines the __index__ special function (indicating it's logically losslessly convertible to int), then this will work.

Seems you have an XY Problem. Check out this Q&A for information on how to properly emulate an int.
